# Как сбросить стандартную AJAX веб-форму Битрикса после успешной отправки?

Tags: битрикс

Форма выводится в попапе.

После отправки посетитель получает сообщение "Ваша заявка успешно отправлена".
Закрывает попап. Снова открывает, а там все то же "Ваша заявка успешно отправлена".

Как можно без ребута страницы сбросить форму до начального состояния?
Есть ли такая возможность у веб-форм Битрикса?

Comment: можно линк на сайт где форма?

Comment: https://online-apteka.com.ua/ В верхнем меню справа Рецепт врача

Comment: ну тут вы никак не сделаете просто через битрикс, поскольку у вас этот попап не через `ajax` подтягивается, а уже на странице есть. Если бы вы его на `ajax` переделали, тогда было бы все ок.

Comment: Остается тогда просто ребутить страницу по закрытию попапа